# PHP Form Validation - Restrict all but alphabetic characters

Tags: php

I have a nice form created and i've been able to create a bunch of restrictions thus far. But i have one form field in which i stricly want it to be letters only. No numbers or special characters. I can create the if statement to spit out an error if someone trys to enter other types of characters, but i need the correct conditional. I've been searching and trying to figure it out but if anyone knows the correct format please let me know!

Comment: That depends on a lot of things, many of which you have not written about in your question. For example the used encoding, Also describing groups of characters as "Numbers" or "Letters" and especially as "Special Characters" is not saying much as the meaning of these groups of characters vary pretty much. So it is very important if you ask about input validation, that you make your cause also technically well defined so it is clear what you're asking about. Also an example is never bad on this website here. Otherwise you'll only get broad answers (as you can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [`ctype_alhpa`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

```
if(ctype_alpha($yourvar))
{
echo "Valid !! They are alphabets !!";
}
else
{
echo "Hey..This field accepts only alphabets !";
}
```

Comment: ctype_alpha() is exactly what i was looking for =) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $string))
    {
      // string contains only english letters
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [PCRE](http://php.net/pcre) like this. (man pcresyntax for more info)

```
define('ALPHA_ONLY_REGEX','/[^a-z]/i');
// by placing a ^ inside the brackets, 
// it tells the regex engine to replace 
// everything but those characters.
// the i tells this to be case insensitive

$clean = preg_replace(ALPHA_ONLY_REGEX, '', $_GET['my_parameter']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!ctype_alpha($myvar)){
    echo"Invalid characters";

    }
```